# Random number from a probability distribution

Tags: random, difference, heuristics, probability-distribution, significance

I have read in a recent metaheuristic  algorithm that a random number is drawn from a uniform distribution.Is there any  difference/ significance in the nature of random number drawn from Normal distribution and Gaussian Distribution/Poisson Distribution?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you explain more why you ask this question?  Also, try asking the question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: With a uniform distribution, every number is equally likely to be returned. In other distributions, e.g. [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), some numbers are more likely than others.

Comment: If you ask why some algorithm or other draws from a _uniform_ distribution as opposed to some other distribution, the reason depends on the specific algorithm, which you should state in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

uniform distribution means every outcome has equal probability to happen.

different Distributions are considering outcomes not that simple and made them more complex.

for example:

think of probability of having one dice faces 6:

its not dependent to any other probable variables, and we suppose each possible outcome equals 1/6.

but when we want probability of sum of **two dice equals to 6** :

it can be more sophisticated since this variable depends on two simple variable:

dice A and dice B, each has an uniform distribution. but sum of the could have another distribution.

sum of two dice is achievable with these:

A:1 B:5 / A:2 B:4 / A:3 B:3 / A:4 B:2 / A:5 B:1

so there is another Distribution.

**The Random Number Generator** suppose there are **No Consideration** and **No Inequality** between probability of outcomes.

its simple as it is, to make he building block of any other distribution with more complex logic.

so its probability distribution is simple as **uniform**.